# Dissable layers in layermanager

Tags: boundless-suite

I´m making an app using opengeo suite SDK and I added a LayerManager to show the layer list and the corresponding leyends. Layers load fine but now I want some of them off by default, added the "selected:false" option on those layers but it doesn´t work and the app loads with all layers enabled.

Any idea how can I load the layers but disabled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sure about this, but would "visibility: false" help?

Comment: Yes it does... dont know why the "Selected" parameter doesn`t work but ss long as I can use the "Visibility" it wil be ok... THX

Comment: It is standard OpenLayers parameter. Since OpenLayers Is used in the suit, I was thinking, it could work. Lucky guess.